# Java RCP Plug-in and Product project

Tags: java, eclipse

A company (here in my town) opened for students "free Java training". We are working with eclipse and today the project manager gives me a new project (tables, data and operation with them), because I have finished the tutorials given by him. I'm learning Java for two weeks and now I get lost. I have no idea where to start or what to do. I have learned and made SWT objects, I know and learned the concepts of OOP, but I have no idea what's the relation between what we have learned and what we are supposed to do. I know what's a Display, a Shell, a Dialog, but now I have no idea where to start.

The Project Manager said that I must create a new Plug-in Project and than a New Product Project with view. What the heck?! A product? What am I supposed to to with it? Where is the main class where I should init. the Display and Shell classes?

Could anyone post a link with tutorials (only SWT no JFace) and examples? I already made my search, but those examples was with IBM and other included packages. I can't use them. I need to use standard widgets.

Thank you !

Comment: RCP takes care of the main method. What you do is define a `plugin.xml` file referencing the classes you develop, then a `.product` file pointing to your plugin(s).

Comment: BTW, this will probably be closed as not constructive : we don't answer with links to tutorials here.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest  you to read below book. It helps you to get started

[http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/0321603788?ie=UTF8&tag=eclipsercp-20&linkCode=as2&camp=1789&creative=390957&creativeASIN=0321603788](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321603788)